# How to build project from Github? Instructions inconclusive

Tags: git, drupal, build

I know this isn't technically an issue with Drupal itself, but my question has been languishing on superuser for almost a month, so I was hoping another Drupal user might have already done this...

I'm a drupal developer using Komodo Edit as an IDE. I recently found a [project](https://github.com/nevergone/drupalforkomodo) on GitHub that would add autocomplete for the drupal API to Komodo's language options. I've never used git before and I'm confused (the fact that I'm on a Mac and new to that as well isn't helping...) Can anyone help me out?

The build instructions per the project page are:

- git clone
  https://github.com/nevergone/drupalforkomodo.git
  followed by cd drupalforkomodo
- If Komodo installed in /opt/komodo/,
  then build command:
  /opt/komodo/lib/sdk/bin/koext build
- Project root directory contain:
  drupal-VERSION-ko.xpi

So I was able to get a clone of the project, but the rest is beyond me. If I were doing this on my home machine running Linux it would be no problem, but the Mac file system is different. Komodo is installed in my Applications directory, but I have no idea where the lib/sdk/and so on is, so how do I complete the next two steps?

I did find the actual installation of Komodo at hardDrive -> Users -> myUser -> Library -> Application Support -> KomodoEdit, but there's no lib/sdk directory anywhere in there. Any ideas?

Comment: This question is more related to Komodo Edit and the Mac, than Drupal.

Comment: I can't migrate my own question... go ahead if that's where you think it belongs. I figured since the project I'm trying to install is Drupal-related it would be more likely that someone who used Drupal would have done it already.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the xpi directly from http://community.activestate.com/files/drupal-0.4.1-ko.xpi. Now you don't have to build it yourself.

Now go to Preferences / Code Intelligence and add the xpi to the API Catalog.

More information available here: http://community.activestate.com/xpi/drupal-extension-komodo

Comment: Many extensions on the community site are out-of-date. This one is listed as last updated in 2009; the git project was just updated in January of this year. The one on the community site doesn't work with the more recent versions of Komodo (or at least, it hasn't been confirmed to work.)

Comment: In fact, as I look more closely, I remember that I found the project on github in the first place by following a link from a comment on the extension you linked to, indicating that the extension had been abandoned on the community site and any new updates would be on git.